# Get GUI of a different class to update continuously using java swing worker

Tags: java, user-interface, swingworker

I am creating a new window of the MainWindow class from within a different class. 
The JFrame of the MainWindow class opens, and I can click my button, but the GUI does not update as it should after the button is clicked. I use SwingWorkers in this class, and if I run it on its own the GUI updates continuously. 
However, creating it from the other class, it is not updating properly, even after I called the creating using a SwingWorker.

```
    private void StartButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
    // TODO add your handling code here:

        WindowEvent winClose = new WindowEvent(this,WindowEvent.WINDOW_CLOSING);
        Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemEventQueue().postEvent(winClose);
        StartGame doGame = new StartGame();
        doGame.execute();

}                                           

class StartGame extends SwingWorker<Void, Void>
{
   @Override
   public Void doInBackground()
   {

    try {
        MainWindow game = new MainWindow(num_respawns, hits, regen_secs, time, map);
        game.setVisible(true);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(GameSetup.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

       return null;
   }
   @Override
   public void done()
   {
       System.out.println("opening done");
   }

}
```

Comment: Probably your code should be run on the EDT. Try `SwingUtilities.invokeLater()`

Comment: Besides read carefully docs for `SwingWorker`. Any GUI updates should bo done on EDT. Methods `publish` and `done` are run on the EDT. `doInBackground` is in background non-deamon thread.

Comment: @Antoniossss do you mean create a new invokeLater method from which the MainWindow will be opened, or do you mean to incorporate this code into the preexisting invokeLater method of the class this is written in?